# Error con async - await en client component NextJs

Tags: next.js, async-await

Estoy utilizando App Router y tengo un problema con async - await en un client component de NextJs, requiero eliminar datos de Firebase, pero al momento de llamar la función **deleteAccounts** no ejecuta el await. Hice la prueba cambiando a un server component y funciona perfectamente. No puedo usar server component porque requiero pasar la función mediante un OnClick

````
import { Flex } from "@tremor/react"
import { firebaseApp } from "@/app/firebase"
import { deleteDoc, doc, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { Suspense } from "react"

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)



export default  function Detail({params}){
    
    const deleteAccounts = async(id)=>{    
        console.log("ID a Eliminar", id)
        await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'accounts', id))
        console.log("eliminado")
    }

    const {id} = params
    return(
        <Flex>
            <Suspense>
            <button onClick={()=>deleteAccounts(id)}>Eliminar</button>
            </Suspense>            
        </Flex>
        
    )
}```

[![la función se ejecuta has el primer console log][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe4iW.png

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar. Muchas Gracias
````

Comment: si guardas `doc(db, 'accounts', id)` en una variable que tenes ahi? Estas capturando bien ese elemento? Para saber si tenes un error en esa llamada a firebase podes envolver el await en un try-catch y consolear el error a ver que pasa.